# Facebook Pixel Not Reporting Leads

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel

We have a Facebook Ad which directs users to a Live Webinar Sign Up Page on another website.

There are multiple steps in the visitor flow:

1) Click Facebook Ad
2) Go to Webinar Sign Up Page
3) Go To Webinar Countdown Page
4) Go To Webinar Registration Thank You Page

We have the Facebook Pixel on 1, 2, and 4 but not #3 page.

On #1 and #2 I have PageView event:

fbq('track', 'PageView');

And on #4 I have TrackLead, which is supposed to show in Facebook Ads Manager custom reporting

fbq('track', 'Lead');

---

My question is does the omission of the Facebook pixel code on page #3 cause this Facebook Pixel / Lead Reporting to not work?

Comment: What behavior are you observing, and how does it differ from what you are expecting? Are you getting the page view events?

Comment: @JonChurch I've run a similar ad before and it worked with the "Cost Per Website Lead" metric showing data in Facebook Ads Manager. That is what's missing: that the 10+ leads that signed up are not showing in "Cost Per Lead" in Ads Manager. This question is much simpler: Will Lead Event Tracking work if one page in the visitor flow is missing the Facebook Pixel? I assume not.

Comment: I think this is likely an issue with the report setup, and not the pixel. However, seeing your code on page 4 would help also. Im going to answer the question you asked, however, "does the omission of the Facebook pixel code on page #3 cause this Facebook Pixel / Lead Reporting to not work?"

Answer (score 0):

**Skipping a page in the flow should not cause lead reporting to stop working on other pages.**

To achieve your goal of seeing [Cost per Wesbite Lead](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1526339040936191), try the following:

**If you are seeing lead events from your Pixel section in the Ads Manager:**
Your pixel is firing properly and recording the event. To see Cost per Website Lead, Make sure you are filtering correctly. In your Ads Manager, filter by `'Cost per Website Lead'`, instead of `'Cost per Lead (form)'` as they are two different kinds of leads.

**If you are not seeing lead events show up in your Pixel section of Facebook Ads Manager**, then the pixel on your site is not firing properly, and there is an issue with your code or the page. There should be plenty of answers that deal with firing a pixel properly.

Comment: According to our data, we have had multiple lead signups and they are not showing in any "Lead column". According to your first statement, they should be.

Comment: @AndrewBriggs Data in facebook you are seeing leads or in an external db?

Comment: We verified that leads are coming in through our webinar software, but they are not showing in Facebook. They should be because the Facebook Track Lead code will fire on the Webinar page.

Comment: Can you maybe ask another question about why your pixel isnt firing and share the code from page 4? It sounds like this is an issue with your pixel code.